# Unity Array of Struct : When setting a variable of one of the array subscripts, it sets it for all of them

Tags: c#, arrays, button, struct, unity-game-engine

This is my struct that I have created.

```
public struct Bar
{

    private static float deltaTime = 1.0f;
    private static bool AutoRun = false;
    private static bool AutoRunBought = false;
    private static bool Start = false;


    // DELTA TIME
    public float GetDeltaTime()
    {
        return deltaTime;
    }
    public void SetDeltaTime(float _dt)
    {
        deltaTime = _dt;
    }
    public void IncrementDeltaTime(float _deltaIn)
    {
        deltaTime += _deltaIn;
    }
    public void DecrementDeltaTime(float _deltaIn)
    {
        deltaTime -= _deltaIn;
    }

    // AUTO RUN
    public bool GetAutoRun()
    {
        return AutoRun;
    }
    public void SetAutoRun(bool _autoBought)
    {
        AutoRunBought = _autoBought;
    }
    public bool GetAutoRunBought()
    {
        return AutoRun;
    }
    public void SetAutoRunBought(bool _autoBought)
    {
        AutoRunBought = _autoBought;
    }

    // START
    public bool GetStart()
    {
        return Start;
    }
    public void SetStart(bool _start)
    {
        Start = _start;
    }
}
```

In my other class I create an instance of that by calling

```
scr_Globals.Bar[] myBars = new scr_Globals.Bar[2];
```

in my Update I am doing

```
if (myBars[0].GetAutoRun() == true) 
    {
        myBars[0].IncrementDeltaTime (incrementBar1);
        if (myBars[0].GetDeltaTime () > 40.0f) {
            myBars[0].SetDeltaTime (1.0f);
            globals.IncrementTotalMoney(1.0f);
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        if (myBars[0].GetStart() == true)
        {
            myBars[0].IncrementDeltaTime (incrementBar1);
            if (myBars[0].GetDeltaTime () > 40.0f) {
                myBars[0].SetDeltaTime (1.0f);
            globals.IncrementTotalMoney(1.0f);
                myBars[0].SetStart(false);
        } 

        }
    }
```

This above code is done for both of the buttons, so I have the same code but for position 1 of the array. 
and I have a button that is created from Unity's UI and when it is clicked it activated a function I have created that sets one of the bools on. That code looks like this

```
    public void OnButton1Click()
{
    myBars[0].SetStart (true);
}
```

Whenever the button is clicked and calls that function it sets both myBars[0] and myBars[1] SetStart to true. Any assistance is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your fields are all static:

```
private static float deltaTime = 1.0f;
private static bool AutoRun = false;
private static bool AutoRunBought = false;
private static bool Start = false;
```

So if you write:

```
Bar x = new Bar();
Bar y = new Bar();
x.SetStart(true);
bool b = y.GetStart();
```

... then `b` will be true. The value returned by `GetStart` doesn't depend on the value you call it on at all...

You don't want those fields to be static - they're meant to represent part of the state of each value, right?

I'd actually advise against mutable structs too, but that's a different matter. I'd *also* advise against all those `GetXyz`/`SetXyz` methods - learn about C# properties instead.

If you're new to C#, I'd really recommend learning it outside the Unity environment first - install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and learn about the basics of the language via console apps etc, with the aid of a good book. You'll be in a much simpler environment to experiment with, and you won't constantly be wondering whether odd behaviour is due to C# or Unity.

Comment: This solved my issue. It was the fact that they were all static variables. And thanks for the advice for the Visual Studio Community Edition. I will be downloading that today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also starting learning C# with `struct` is probably not the best idea. Errors one gets from incorrect usage are way more puzzling than incorrect usage of reference types.